# Use importdata with more than 4 digits precision

Tags: matlab

My data is a mixture of strings and values tab delimited. 'Importdata' is working pretty well but doesn't have a higher precision than 4 digits. How can I fix that, because I really need more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a small example of your input data, so we can check the format?

Comment: Thanks, `format long` worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab shows you by default only a precision of 4 digits - but calculates with much more digits internally.
Try

```
format long
```

to see a more precise representation of your data

Comment: I have tried it and it looked like it didn't work in first instance. Now it does. Thanks!